# Rails 6, Devise and Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise and Active Storage in my rails 6 application. Currently using `before_action: authenticate_user!` disables all images for non users, which is great, except I want to allow images with the `record_type` 'News' in my `active_storage_attachments` to be viewable by users and non users.

The below code is what I have so far, looking at ActiveStorage::Attachment where the `record_type` is News. This code shows all images for both users and non users which is not ideal.

```
class ActiveStorage::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :allow_certain_assets
  include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  
  private
  
  def allow_certain_assets
    if (ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(record_type: 'News')).present?
    else
      authenticate_user!
    end
  end
  
end
```

Comment: You should describe how are you accessing the attachment. If you want to protect the attachment at controller level it is one thing, if you want to protect at the model level it is another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is you are doing this:

```
(ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(record_type: 'News')).present?
```

which will check the whole database if there is any `attachment` with `record_type` 'News'. But instead you need to check if the particular image the user is trying to access is of 'News' type then allow him or else don't allow him. One way to do this would be on the show action you can check:

```
def show
  # this code might be incorrect and I am not sure how you would be getting 
  # the attachment object but this would explain a way you can authenticate it
  @attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find params[:id]
  authenticate_user! unless @attachment.record_type == 'News'
end
```

So this will check the particular object the user is trying to access.

**Add on:**

This type of authorization can be done automatically using some authorization libraries like:

1. [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)
2. [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit)

where you can allow certain type of images for guest user too and the other type of images only for a registered user.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Deep. I've had no luck with your test above. Get an error: Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Attachment without an ID

Comment: I told you this is just an example I am not sure how you would get that object, your `params[:id]` is nil that is why it is giving you this exception. The main idea is to apply the authorization to single object which is being accessed instead of all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be used with [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) gem (one of the options mentioned by @Deep [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63546542/188574))

```
# controller
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    authorize :image, :index?
    @images = policy_scope(ActiveRecord::Attachment)
  end

  def show
    @image = policy_scope(ActiveRecord::Attachment).find(params[:id])
    authorize @image, policy_class: ImagePolicy
  end
end
```

```
# policy
class ImagePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    true # must be true so that every can see the list
  end

  def show?
    true # optional: add more logic here
  end

  class Scope
    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user  = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      if user
        scope
      else        
        scope.where(record_type: 'News') # we limit the records here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here were helpful for my use case but if anyone else has difficulty getting at the original record to do model specific stuff (as I did) then [find_signed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/signed_id.rb#L42) might be useful to get the info you need for other checks, conditionals etc.

```
class ActiveStorage::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent
  before_action :check_attachment
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  
  private

  def check_attachment
    blob_id = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:signed_id])
    attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_by(blob_id: blob_id)
    record = attachment.record_type.constantize.find(attachment.record_id)
    if # Other model specific checks
      # Can also redirect somewhere else here if needed:
      # redirect_to root_path, alert: 'You do not have permission to access this.'
    end
  end
end
```